# WPF Drag And Drop DataBinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, drag-and-drop

Hey guys, 
I'm starting to wrap WPF around my head and I came to a dead end.

I have a ListBox that accepts files/folders by drag and drop. I have a Files Class witch contains files properties like "Name", "Thumbnail" [and so on] and a FilesCollection Class well it's self intuitive. The Collection takes a "FilesPath" and then it retrieves all the files from that path.
Currently it has a static path associated with it but I want that path to change when I drag a folder to the ListBox.

So what I want is:

- when I drag a folder to the ListBox, associate the path of it to the FilesCollection Class

Comment: so, you want to know how to do file-drag and drop or how to enumerate files into your FilesCollection ?

Comment: I want to know how to bind my FilesCollection "FilesPath" property to the path of the folder that is dragged into the ListBox.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think that it can be implemented using a Parent property and a global event "FolderPathChanged". Each item subscribes to the event and check whether the source can be reached in hierarchy of parents. Something like that, it is just a theoretical hypothesis, I don't know what will happen at practice.

Comment: This should be two questions: `How to drag a folder into a ListBox and get the folder path?` (which I have covered); and `how to bind to a string in WPF?` (which has been covered exhaustively in other questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set AllowDrop to True and handle the Drop event.

The ListBox definition:

```
<ListBox AllowDrop="True" Drop="ListBox_Drop"> </ListBox>
```

The event handler:

```
private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileName"))
    {
        string folderPath = e.Data.GetData("FileName");
        //do whatever you need to do with the folder path
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd go with this. There is such a thing as wanting to bind too badly when one or two lines of code would suffice.